# API SendMessage() does not work for external app dialog

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

I created a form that has 2 buttons. One button pops a msgbox and the other runs form frmAPI (code is listed below) listed below. If I open the msgbox and leave it open and then run the frmAPI it will list the msgbox and its text and then close it. THis is what I expect it to do. If I open another application and generate a msgbox in that app with my frmAPI still running it will in fact list the other apps msgbox and the text but it does not close the msgbox from the other app. If Irun the frmAPI from the other app and do the same test the results are reversed. So in short it will only close the dialog from within the same app.

I would like to be able to close a dialog from any app based on it being a dialog and having text that will match my criteria. Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Partial Public Class TestMSgBoxStuff
    Inherits Form
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowText(hWnd As IntPtr, lpString As StringBuilder, nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As HandleRef, Msg As UInteger, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32", CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function


    Private Const WM_IME_NOTIFY As Integer = &H282
    Private Const WM_DESTROY As Integer = &H2
    Private Const WM_NCDESTROY As Integer = &H82
    Private Const WM_CLOSE As Integer = &H10
    Private Const IMN_CLOSESTATUSWINDOW As Integer = &H1
    Private Const WM_KILLFOCUS As Integer = &H8
    Private Const WM_COMMAND As Integer = &H11



    Private Sub TestMSgBoxStuff_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim timer As New Timer()
        Timer1.Interval = 10000
        'detect the MessageBox every seconds
        'Timer1.Tick += New EventHandler(Timer1_Tick)
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'Get the MessageBox handle
        Dim handle As IntPtr = FindWindow("#32770", Nothing)
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Handle: " + handle.ToString() + vbLf)

        'Get the Text window handle
        Dim txtHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Static", Nothing)
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbTab & "text handle: " + txtHandle.ToString() + vbLf)
        Dim len As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(txtHandle)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        'Get the text
        GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1)
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbTab & "text: " + sb.ToString() + vbLf & vbLf)
        Me.RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()

        SetForegroundWindow(handle)

        'close the messagebox WM_CLOSE
        Dim lResults As Integer = SendMessage(New HandleRef(Nothing, handle), WM_NCDESTROY, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sending WM_NCDESTROY does not destroy a window. [It merely prank-calls the window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/26/10216420.aspx). If your goal is to automate the Close button, then use the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace. Read the `Name` property to get the text of the message box, and use `InvokePattern.Invoke()` to push the OK button.

Comment: I was using the WM_Close option and then attempted to use the WM_Destroy based on another article I read. This is good thing to know thanks. As for using the system.windows.automation namespace will this work for all dialogs regardless of where it originated? and does this mean I would no longer be using the windows API methods?

Comment: The Automation namespace can control anything that has UI (and which exposes itself via accessibility, which most apps do at least at a basic level because Windows provides a basic one automatically). Not sure what you mean by the second question. You're using the Automation methods (which wrap the appropriate Windows API methods).

Comment: I understand what your saying with "You're using the automation methods(which wrap the appropriate WindowsAPI Methods)" as indicating I will not need to bother with API calls directly to interface with the dialogs I can use the net framework. However, when I attempted to investigate the namespace I get the error "Automation is not a member of windows"

Comment: Um, that just means that you didn't add the necessary references. This is not a problem specific to System.Windows.Automation. This is a general issue with programming with .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into [User Interface Privilege Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation). That'll block your messages from going to a higher privilege process. See also [`ChangeWindowsMessageFilter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I'd suggest trying to send it a [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of a `WM_CLOSE`; `WM_COMMAND` is generally treated more gently by the system and may get through. Use BN_CLICKED as the high word of WPARAM and IDOK as the low word (assuming it has an OK button), and the handle to the OK button in LPARAM.. Other button messages are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't you think that sending the wrong message is a more serious problem. No amount of UIPI mitigation can fix that.

Comment: This morning I started my apps up and attempted to use the WM_COMMAND code on a SQL dialog asking if I wanted to save my changes on a query. THere were 3 options. My app broke on this line: GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1) with a string builder error. If I skipped the line it then worked. I then changed it back to WM_Close and it also now works. This is a bit confusing to me. Could the WM_COMMAND changed something with the rights?